# Enabling Save for an NSDocument

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument

I am using an NSDocumentController subclass to do some custom stuff when I create my NSDocuments. The strange thing is that when the document is created, the Save option in the menu is disabled. The problem is that I use the save function to save something manually out from the document so it's decoupled from the main NSDocument saving procedure. Normally I use         [self updateChangeCount: NSChangeDone] when I make changes in the document, but that doesn't seem to have any effect on enabling the Save menu item when the document is created.

I use [NSDocument saveToURL] when it's first created, so that might be what's disabling save afterwards. Is there a way for me to force it to be saveable again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you explored using either of these?

**NSDocument**

```
- (BOOL)isDocumentEdited
```

**NSDocumentController**

```
- (BOOL)hasEditedDocuments
```

Answer (score 3):

I battled this for ages. In my case, the problem was that I hadn't linked the File's owner window outlet to my Window in the nib when I converted to a document-based app.

Comment: How to do this?